# If the drift velocity of the electron is too low then how they can oscillate very fast in a high frequency alternating current?

Tags: electricity, harmonic-oscillator

As we know the drift velocity of electrons inside a current carrying conductor is $\sim 10^{-4}$ m/s and with this if it's an alternating current with a very high frequency let's say 10 kHz then how can the electrons travel very fast so that they can complete 10k cycles in just 1 second despite of having a very small drift velocity?

Also, how will the energy get transferred to the load if the electrons are not entering the power source and just oscillating (if it is) about it's mean position to take the energy from the source and put it into the load? and if the case is not like that then how the energy is transferred In the load In the case of AC.

Please focus more on the first question, I want to understand this thing.

Comment: What is the average value of ac current?

Comment: You didn’t answer my question. What is the average value of any sinusoidal current?

Comment: I was just confused what you were actually asking because average value for half cycle (that I took was 2 amps) is something else that is 0.637 times its peak value. Now I get it what you were asking, the answer will be zero If it's for one cycle then the answer would be just zero.

Comment: @TejasDahake The periodic motion you are referring to stems from instantaneous velocity (as opposed to drift velocity). Drift velocity is really a definition as opposed to $m_{e} d\vec v(t)/dt=\vec F=q_{\rm e}\vec E(t)$ (assuming no resistance).

Comment: @Newbie yes I know it is, but I think this is not the correct answer to help me to get out of this problem.

Comment: @Newbie you can't assume zero resistance because the drift velocity is only possible because of the presence of resistance. Then the thing like drift velocity won't exist the electron will keep accelerating all the time in the case you are thinking about.

Comment: @TejasDahake 1. That assumption was only for illustrating my point. 2. You are wrong because even without resistance the field is periodically changing direction.

Comment: @TejasDahake If the average value of sinusoidal current is zero, what does that tell you about the average value of drift velocity? You might find this interesting: https://www.scienceabc.com/nature/what-is-the-speed-of-electricity.html

Comment: @Newbie Yes I know brother that the field is still changing the direction but I only told that the thing like drift velocity won't exist because there is no resistance so it will accelerate and again decelerate and this will keep happening all the time but that will not be the drift velocity. Drift is defined as the distance between the two successive collisions and if there will be nothing to collide inside the conductor then there won't be any term like drift and hence the drift velocity..

Comment: @TejasDahake Even without an external electric field the electrons are colliding (i.e, resistance). Drift is defined based on the external electric field, not collisions.

Comment: @Newbie but before you were telling that you excluded the the resistance so I was just focusing on that statement. Seems a bit confusing that what are you exactly trying to tell me. And also seems that you are not getting my point clearly

Comment: @TejasDahake The simplest way to put it is this: Without an electric field the electrons collide but the drift velocity is 0. It is with an external force that you can push the electrons in a single direction. In other words, even though there will always be collisions, i.e., resistance, its the external field which causes drift. I think I’m repeating myself multiple times now and I hope you’ve got your answer.

Comment: @Newbie now I get to know the only point is the electrons moves forward in the presence of external electric field and the electrons still collide with each other, other atoms, and their vacancies in the presence of heat energy which will get converted in the kinetic energy of the electrons because of some temperature difference between the surroundings and the conductor but they move randomly anywhere so the net-velocity remains zero and hence the current remains zero as well...okay that what you are telling me?

Comment: @Newbie But I'm already aware of these things and this seems irrelevant to our topic but, thank you for investing your precious time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The charge carriers do their slight back-and-forth wiggle *everywhere* in the whole current loop  I.e. in the energy source, the wires, and the load. So from the point of view of the load, current is being pushed through it alternatingly, all the time, doing work against the load's resistance.

The electric field which makes the electrons move is mediated through the circuit much faster than the drift velocity, namely on the order of the speed of light. So one can simplify that all the electrons in the circuit know at once when and how to move and they all move collectively.

### How fast can electrons change their drift velocity? Isn't 10 kHz very fast ?

It's important to realize that conduction electrons have a much (much!) higher statistical velocity in all directions (search 'Fermi velocity'). But in average it is zero (no current). The drift velocity is only the slight shift of the average speed. Electrons have also tiny inertia, changing speed of many km/s² (probably actually orders of magnitude more even) all the time..So again the slight drift velocity change at 10 kHz is absolutely negligible. I.e. kHz AC currents are quasistatic changes of the state in the conductor.

Comment: This is right but let's assume an instant at which the electric field is only directed towards on direction at that point of time the electrons will move opposite to the direction of field (as they are negatively charged) that means a drift velocity will be induced but that is very less in magnitude and as soon as the direction of field gets changed the force will act in the opposite direction as that was before so it will decelerate the electrons and induce the velocity in opposite direction as well so it will take much more time to do this till then again the direction of electric field....

Comment: .....will be reversed due to the high frequency as describes in the question so how is it possible to complete the one cycle for an electron in presence of all these things that's what I'm trying to ask here.

Comment: @TejasDahake Then please edit your question and include your 2 paragraphs of explanations and clarifications in it.

Comment: @Newbie it's just the same case man! But provided some in detail information to the answerer so that he may help me out of this if he can.

Comment: @TejasDahake It's important to realize that conduction electrons have a much (much!) higher statistical velocity in all directions (search 'Fermi velocity'). But in average it is zero (no current). The drift velocity is only the slight shift of the average speed. Electrons have also tiny inertia, changing speed of many km/s² (probably actually orders of magnitude *more* even) all the time..So again the slight drift velocity change at 10 kHz is absolutely negligible. I.e. kHz AC currents are quasistatic changes of the state in the conductor.

Comment: @tobalt OH, I got your point.

Answer (score 2):

Energy transfer from component $A$ to component $B$  is not accomplished by moving electrons from $A$ to $B$. It is accomplished by establishing a "guided" electromagnetic field and its associated [Poynting vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector).

The wires or cables of an electrical circuit or the antenna of a broadcast station produce shaped electromagnetic fields. These shaped fields have both electrical and magnetic fields (vectors) which have a directional power flow. It's not the moving charges that carry the power, it's the electromagnetic (not simply the electrical) field.

In AC circuits, the power source changes the direction of the electrical field causing electrons in the wires to move, generally, parallel to the wires, producing time-varying magnetic fields. The resulting electromagnetic wave carries the energy flow to other components connected to the wires because the wires shape the fields.

Answer (score 1):

An electron doesn't need to travel very fast to complete 10K cycles if the oscillation amplitude is very small. And the effective amplitude will be very small here because the random disturbances in the material don't actually allow any proper sinusoidal oscillations. There is merely a small oscillating component superposed on the (overall quasi-stationary) random component, as much as the drift velocity is just a small constant component superposed on the random motion in case of DC fields.